# JPA Composite Key + Sequence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, composite-key

Is it possible in plain JPA or JPA+Hibernate extensions to declare a composite key, where an element of the composite key is a sequence?

This is my composite class:

```
@Embeddable
public class IntegrationEJBPk implements Serializable {

    //...


    @ManyToOne(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "APPLICATION")
    public ApplicationEJB getApplication() {
        return application;
    }


    @Column(name = "ENTITY", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public String getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "INTEGRATION_ID_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "INTEGRATION_ID_GEN", sequenceName = "OMP_INTEGRATION_CANONICAL_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "CANONICAL_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public String getCanonicalId() {
        return canonicalId;
    }

    @Column(name = "NATIVE_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public String getNativeId() {
        return nativeId;
    }

    @Column(name = "NATIVE_KEY", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public String getNativeKey() {
        return nativeKey;
    }

    //...
}
```

I already supply the values for `application`, `entity`, `nativeId` and `nativeKey`. I want to construct an entity like the one below:

```
IntegrationEJB i1 = new IntegrationEJB();
i1.setIntegrationId(new IntegrationEJBPk());
i1.getIntegrationId().setApplication(app1);
i1.getIntegrationId().setEntity("Entity");
i1.getIntegrationId().setNativeId("Nid");
i1.getIntegrationId().setNativeKey("NK");
```

And when I call `em.persist(i1`), I want that the `canonicalId` is generated and the integration is inserted.

Is this possible? If so, what's the simple way? (I prefer not to use application-provided keys or native sql).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is not possible with plain JPA.

Comment: It is possible. The only way I've found requires the Id parts to not be insertable or updatable. Wanted to clarify outdated post as this is a top hit in search results.

Comment: The `@GeneratedValue` annotation is [not supported](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/GeneratedValue) for composite primary keys.

Comment: here is the updated link: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4552

Answer (score 2):

Using @GeneratedValue for composite PKs is not specified withi JPA 2 spec.

From the JPA spec:

> 11.1.17 GeneratedValue Annotation
>
> The GeneratedValue annotation provides for the specification of
>   generation strategies for the values of primary keys. The
>   GeneratedValue annotation may be applied to a primary key property or
>   field of an entity or mapped superclass in conjunction with the Id
>   annotation.[97]  The use of the GeneratedValue annotation is only
>   required to be supported for simple primary keys. Use of the
>   GeneratedValue annotation is not supported for derived primary keys.

Note that under a different scenario, you can have a parent entity with a simple PK (@Id) that uses @GeneratedValue, and then have a child entity that has a composite PK that includes the generated Id from the parent, plus another column.

- Give the child a @ManyToOne relationship to the parent entity, so that it inherits the generated ID in a FK column.
- Then give the child a composite PK, via @IdClass specified against the entity, plus two @Id columns within the entity.

> ```
> @Entity
> public class ParentEntity {
> ```

```
       @Id
       @GenerateValue(IDENTITY) // If using DB auto-increment or similar
       int id;

       // ...
}
```

> ```
> @Entity
> @IdClass(ChildId.class)
> public class ChildEntity {
>    // The child table will have a composite PK:
>    // (parent_ID, child_name)
>        @Id 
>        @ManyToOne
>        int parentEntity;
> ```

```
       @Id
       String childName;

       String favoriteColor;  // plus other columns

       // ...

}
```

> ```
> // child Id attributes have the same name as the child entity
> // however the types change to match the underlying PK attributes 
> // (change ParentEntity to int)
>  public class ChildId implements Serializable {
> ```

```
        int parentEntity;
        String childName;

        public ChildId() { //... }

        // Add extra constructor & remove setter methods so Id objects are immutable
        public ChildId(int parentEntity, String childName) { //... }


        public int getParentEntity() { //... }
        // make Id objects immutable:
        //  public void setParentEntity(int parentEntity) { //... }
        public String getChildName() { //... }
        //  public void setChildName(String childName) { //... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
@TableGenerator(name = "canonicalKeys", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "canonicalKeys")
@Column(name = "CANONICAL_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
public String getCanonicalId() {
    return canonicalId;
}
```

In this way instead of using a sequence you can use a table.

Comment: I have to use a sequence, since I cannot change my database model.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that it appears your building a composite primary key like this [example](http://boris.kirzner.info/blog/archives/2008/07/19/hibernate-annotations-the-many-to-many-association-with-composite-key/). While I was poking at a similar problem in my own database I wondered if maybe you could call the sql directly like:

`select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')`

I suppose that would be cheating though ;-)